# Why does the PostgreSQL 16.0 EDB installer fail when using its own generated data folder for installation?

Tags: postgresql, enterprisedb, datadirectory, pg-catalog, postgresql-16

We are using the recently released [PostgreSQL 16 Windows x86-64 installer](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads) to automatically install PostgreSQL 16.0 on our customer systems via a script. The installation works fine the first time. After running the generated uninstaller, it leaves behind the data folder. Running the same installer again now, it seems to have problems with that data folder and displays the following error message:

*The existing data directory (catalog version: 202307071) is not compatible with this server (catalog version: PG_CATALOG_VERSION).*

Screenshot from the GUI:

[image]

**What problems does the PostgreSQL installer have with the data folder it just generated?** I tried this on several machines, as well as on a completely blank VM, always the same error. Trying the same with the previously released PostgreSQL 15.4 installer works fine.

Comment: Looks weird, particularly the literal `PG_CATALOG_VERSION`. You should complain to EnterpriseDB, who made the installer.

Comment: I checked their website, there is no (at least no obvious, maybe I didn't see it) way to contact them regarding their installers, there is also no bug reporting system in place or anything like that

Comment: it's a feature not a bug ;) . it won't delete the Data folder since all your database files are there. If you have backup you can manually delete that folder and install potgrsql again

Comment: @eshirvana I think you misunderstood the question. The question is: why does it have problems with the data folder when reinstalling version 16, while it works fine with older versions. I know that it leaves behind the data folder, that is also what I want.

Comment: Impossible to answer for me, only the one who made this decision knows why: Ask EDB, they made and maintain this installer. You could write your own installer, if you want to, and make a different decision about what to do with an existing data folder.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Any idea how I can reach the devs of the installer?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this works as the owner of the installer intended.

Comment: I don't think it does work as intended. I think there is a high chance that this is a bug, since the previously released installers work differently. Also the error message doesn't make that much sense?

Comment: Also obvious, but I want to mention it:  The installer should not think that the data folder it creates itself is incompatible with the PostgreSQL version it is trying to install. This cannot be intended.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I'm pretty sure it doesn't work as intended, but either way it isn't on topic for this stack.

Comment: @jjanes Do you have any contacts at EDB that work on the installer?

Answer (score 1):

EDB released a new installer: [PostgreSQL 16.1](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads). They fixed this issue.